# Extremely low accuracy on own data in caffe

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I'm trying to train a network on my own data. Whole dataset consists of 256x256 jpeg images. There is 236 objects for classification. Training and validation sets have ~247K and ~61K images, respectively. I've made LMDBs from them using `$CAFFE_ROOT/build/tools/convert_imageset` utility.

Just for starting I'm using caffenet's topology for my model. During training I come across the weird message "Data layer prefetch queue empty" that I never seen before.

Moreover, initially, network has an abnormal accuracy (~0.00378378) and during next 1000 iterations, it reaches max ~0.01 and further does not increase (just fluctuates).

What I'm doing wrong and how can I improve the accuracy?

Runtime log:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/15568421/

Model:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/15568426/

Solver:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/15568430/

P.S. I'm using the latest version of Caffe, Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS and g2.2xlarge instance on AWS.

Comment: try replacing all `"ReLU"` activations with `"PReLU"`, it's a bit slower, but works better if you start from scratch. Moreover, you may try to set `debug_info: true` in your `solver.prototxt` file.

Comment: This sounds a lot like hyperparameters, especially learning rate. You can experiment with many fewer iterations until you get well behaved training error. See [link](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/)

Comment: To clarify the "Data layer prefetch queue empty"-part, see here: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/3177 This means that this message is not directly related to your main problem.